# What is best size to design psd for including iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6 plus

Tags: application-design

What is best size to design psd for including iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6 plus

[image]

Comment: There is no "best size". You will need different sizes. Best to read Apple's documentation about this. Or ask the app developers at your place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best size but I should develop it for the most sold phones

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, please follow the official iOS Human Interface Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/overview/themes/.

---

Also:

#### If you have limited resources

Design for the smallest device (aka **iPhone 4**), and you're garantied that all the elements will also fit on a larger screen.

#### If you have classic resources

Prepare psd for all possible sizes that you support, because the **layout** will often be different:

- 4 inches
- 4.7 inches
- 5.5 inches
- iPhone X
- iPad sizes eventually

#### If you have too much resources

Prepare psd for:

- both portrait and landscape
- and for all class sizes combinations (Any/Compact/Regular height x Any/Compact/Regular width)
- and for all languages (German/Chinese/Arabic often require different layouts)
- and for all iOS versions (because the navigation bar background or the app icon corners have evolved through history)
- and specify all transitions animations+curves+durations